# What control did Github for Windows use, to show History?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I already search it on google about listview and datagrid but there's no one tell how to customize these control

Comment: You can get something like this in WPF for example with a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) and some [DataTemplates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx), these both links should get you a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, i'm new in WPF. this reference is a good start for me

Answer (score 1):

According to [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) it's a custom control named `GitHub.UI.ListBoxEx`. Since the project is not open source, no source is available with it.